# Order of \usepackage causes error with footnote and xcolor

Tags: color, packages, footnotes

Attempting to compile the following,

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{solution}
Hello.\footnote{Goodbye.}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

I get an error on the line calling `\footnote` about a spurious group-closing symbol. If, instead of the `xcolor` package, I use something else like `amsmath` or `fullpage`, no error occurs. Furthermore, if I switch the order of the `\usepackage` statements for `xcolor` and `footnote`, no error occurs.

From reading [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424938/how-to-know-the-order-of-usepackage-in-the-preamble), I saw that some packages require the ordering of `\usepackage` to be a certain way. Is this one of those cases, or is something else going on? Intuitively, `footnote` and `xcolor` seem completely unrelated.

Comment: No error if you comment out `xcolor`. Let's see why.

Comment: Also, no error if you load `xcolor` before `footnote`.

Comment: Considering how many packages use color (even \normalcolor), one should always load xcolor first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footnote package contains the line

```
 \let\fn@endnote\color@endgroup
```

This is a problem if `\color@endgroup` changes its definition *after*  the footnote package has been loaded (and this happens if you load xcolor).

So the recommendation is to load xcolor earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the updated `footnotehyper` package instead of `footnote`, which fixes a number of other things along with this:

```latex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makesavenoteenv{solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{solution}
Hello.\footnote{Goodbye.}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```